# SceneConfiguration Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm getting this error when trying to run flutter app to IOS devices, this error occurs when launching the application on the device for the first time.

Comment: Just ignore it, it's not important.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't actually use scenes, this warning can appear for a few reasons. Most common I've noticed is using a LaunchScreen.storyboard sort of thing, they contain scene data. If indeed you don't use scenes. You can get rid of this by being explicit in your `Info.plist`. Add the following;

```
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict/>
    </dict>
```

If you are managing your `Info.plist` with **Targets > Info > Custom iOS Target Properties** you would set `Application Scene Manifest` like the picture
[image]

Comment: I get the following error: `Unexpectedly received animationDidStop without a matching animationDidStart. Monitoring for idle animations may no longer function correctly.`